90s Disney series where people talk to a virtual assistant on computer
I am trying to identify a 90s Disney series where people talk to a virtual assistant (animated) on a computer monitor. The character name is also "virtual" (I think).
The theme was not about gameshow, but as I recall, it was in an office setting. Where a 3d virtual assistant with a face interacts with adults (not kids).

Welcome to Movies & TV SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

It's a stretch (and not Disney) but the "Mentors" TV series had a virtual, on-screen assistant named "Visicron".

Live action, or animated? If animated, is it 2D or 3D? While not Disney (unless it was overseas), I recall a kids game show in the 90s where the contestants interact with a virtual assistant on a computer, which I think was called "Virtually Impossible".

Disney's Smart House? It fits the timeframe, but it was mostly kids interacting with the computer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px32NZUht4U

Mission: Top Secret had quite a lot of episodes based around an office setting; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoGqWFcglSY
